# find_elements_by_xpath for existing element in a list not being added

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Sorry for the horrible title. I'm trying to create a list of players from basketball-reference.com (the actual page is https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2024.html, in the Roster table).

The list of players is different on each team so I don't want to create an array of set size. Instead I created a variable called players_list, which I would use to get the total number of players, but when actually using it and printing out the length, I always get 0.

```
team_selection = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td/a[contains(text(), "Boston Celtics")]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", team_selection)
players_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td[@data-stat="player"]')
print(len(players_list))
```

It finds at least one of the elements, but I don't know why it's always returning 0 for length when it should be finding 17 matching elements.

Comment: This might not matter, but on that page I see that the tr element tags have an extra space at the end, i.e. they are `<tr >` instead of `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the table id and its `td` children: `//table[@id='roster']/tbody/tr`
Make sure you wait until the data is accessible with `WebDriveWait`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2024.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "roster"))
)
players_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='roster']/tbody/tr")
...
driver.close()
```

*The above code uses the latest selenium [4.17.2] commands, as `find_elements_by_xpath` is deprecated.*

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have made the change you suggested but the underlying problem is still the same. My issue wasn't that the element as I wrote it was never found, my issue is that multiple of those elements exist (in this case, different rows - each representing a different player), but when I print out the length of players_list, it always returns 0.

Comment: This may be because you are trying to access the player list too early. So you have to wait until the player table is accessible. I have edited my answer with a working example.

Comment: players_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="roster"]/tbody/tr/td[@data-stat="player"]/a')
time.sleep(1)
print(len(players_list))

That's my updated code, I've added a 1 second delay. The script finishes running with no errors, but I get 0 as the output of print(len(players_list))

Comment: You better use `WebDriverWait` with a maximum waiting time. The code is continued as soon as the desired element becomes available. The code in the answer works, so you can adapt as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Selenium.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

html = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2024.html')
players = list(pd.read_html(html.text)[0]['Player'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(players)
['Payton Pritchard', 'Sam Hauser', 'Jayson Tatum', 'Jaylen Brown', 'Derrick White', 'Jrue Holiday', 'Al Horford', 'Kristaps Porziņģis', 'Luke Kornet', 'Oshae Brissett', 'Dalano Banton', 'Neemias Queta (TW)', 'Svi Mykhailiuk', 'Lamar Stevens', 'Jordan Walsh', 'JD Davison (TW)', 'Drew Peterson (TW)']
```